# How to get an Array data with custom Component in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I Pass an Array of data to a custom component in Vue js and want to have it in a  that is defined in my template, but I get an error of Missing required prop: "students". here is my code.

custom Component:

```
customElements.define('students-list', defineCustomElement({
template: `<ul :classes="classes">
                <li v-for="st in students"
                    :key="st.name">
                    {{ st.name }}
                </li>
            </ul>
                </div>`,
props: {
    classes: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    students: {
        type: Array,
        required: true
    }

},
data() {
    return {
        
    }
}
```

}));

and the code I use to call it is:

```
<students-list classes="col-sm-12" :students = "[{name: 'John'},{name: 'Sarah'},{name: 'Dave'}]"></students-list>
```

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with this. Could it be that you have another instance of `students-list` somewhere else in your code, where you are not passing an array of `students`?

Comment: @shaaraa I added an answer. Did you get a chance to look into that ? I hope that will help you in understanding the use case and will work as per your requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code, it seems you are trying to access the array of data from your parent component to child component which is `<students-list>`. If Yes, Here you go **:**

```js
Vue.component('studentslist', {
  // declare the props
  props: ['students'],
  // just like data, the prop can be used inside templates
  // and is also made available in the vm as this.message
  template: `<div>
                     <ul>
                <li v-for="st in students"
                    :key="st.name">
                    {{ st.name }}
                </li>
            </ul>
                    </div>`
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <studentsList classes="col-sm-12" :students="[{name: 'John'},{name: 'Sarah'},{name: 'Dave'}]"></studentsList>
</div>
```

Comment: HI Rohit, I have a custom component named studentlist, I want to use this component frequently and I want to pass a json trough that <studentlist data="[{json}]">.I don't want to give data in my component, I want my component to recieve data from that html tag.

Comment: @shaaraa Yes you can do that like i did in the demo, instead of passing that from data property, you can directly pass that in HTML template.

Comment: @shaaraa I improved my answer as per your comment. Hope it will work as per your expectation now.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to define a function in your methods like

```js
students() {
  return [{name: 'John'},{name: 'Sarah'},{name: 'Dave'}];
},
```

and switch

```js
:students = "[{name: 'John'},{name: 'Sarah'},{name: 'Dave'}]"
```

to

```js
:students="students"
```

Comment: but the problem is that I want to get that data from that custom component.

Comment: You probably will still get the data.

Comment: Sorry, I think I asked my question the wrong way,I want to pass that Array of data only through the <students-list> tag.

Comment: You probably will have no luck with that. The way you defined it, it will pass it on as a literal string.